# Cannot update Supabase table because it does not have a replica identity

Tags: supabase

When trying to my first table update using Supabase, with code like:

```
await db.from("welcome").update({visit_count: newCount});
```

Got error:

```
{
  "hint":"To enable updating the table, set REPLICA IDENTITY using ALTER TABLE.",
  "details":null,"code":"55000",
  "message":"cannot update table \"welcome\" because it does not have a replica identity and publishes updates"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this instance, the problem was that I had created the `welcome` table without a primary key.

This error is not really anything to do with Supabase, it's a Postgres error relating to logical replication: https://pgdash.io/blog/postgres-replication-gotchas.html

There's a couple of solutions:

- make sure you have a primary key column
- use the `alter table` command to set a specific set of columns as `replica identity`
- use the `alter table` command to set the `replica identity` to `full`.